# Zend Mail 1.12 lose line break

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

when I try to get content from and email sent by yahoo.com with [zend mail](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.read.html) .
Mail sent:

```
hello.
yeah1
yeah2
YAHOO!
```

reveiced from zend mail:

```
hello.=20 
yeah1yeah2YAHOO!=20
```

using this code

```
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($message) as $numPart => $part) {
    $content = Zend_Mime_Decode::decodeQuotedPrintable($part->getContent());
    echo "<textarea style='height: 400px;'>".($content)."</textarea>";
}
```

I don't understand why it losing line break. 
Working fine with gmail / outlook